# automating build process with jenkins, Github and Selenium

Tags: github, build-automation

We want to automate our build process. We have a Jenkins server and Github repo for development team (devrepo) and separate repro for Selenium ( automationrepo).

Now our need is that whenever the code is pushed to the devrepo then selenium script from the automation repo should be fired ?

Is this doable ? If yes then how ?

I integrated devrepo with jenkins for testing and created a test project on jenkins which fires a build as soon as someone pushes code to devrepo. But now I am not getting how can I integrate the automationrepo so that the automation code is fired when devrepo is updated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Jenkins allows you to initiate a deployment job using an api, and you can git hooks to trigger that api whenever code is pushed on the repository. Now using server-side hooks would have been easier, if you were hosting the git repository on your own servers, instead of github. Since GitHub won't let you run any custom code on their own servers, you can either use client-side git hooks or you can customize your github repository to hit some api hosted on your own servers.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/

Comment: How can I initiate selenium script which is also on github ?

Comment: As I have written in my updated answer, you can't run any custom code on github servers. All you can do is create an api that runs your selenium code and configure github to hit that api in effect to a certain event.